# R: lapply and tibble not working as expected in two loop

Tags: r, lapply, tibble

I have a set of code that loops through all possible scenarios that I use for a drilldown feature in my shiny application. However, the `Level_3_Drilldowns` isn't working as expected as I am not getting my defined `tibble` names.

Below is a single output for Level_2_Drilldowns which is producing what is expected:

```
[[3]]
[[3]]$id
[1] "ocean"

[[3]]$type
[1] "column"

[[3]]$data
[[3]]$data[[1]]
[[3]]$data[[1]]$name
[1] "Boat"

[[3]]$data[[1]]$y
[1] 2

[[3]]$data[[1]]$PerTotal
[1] 37

[[3]]$data[[1]]$drilldown
[1] "ocean_boat"
```

Here, I can see that `name`, `y`, and `PerTotal` are defined (I need to be able to reference them in my graph tooltip)

Below is a single output for Level_3_Drilldowns which is **not** producing what is expected:

```
[[5]]
[[5]]$id
[1] "ocean_boat"

[[5]]$type
[1] "column"

[[5]]$data
[[5]]$data[[1]]
[[5]]$data[[1]][[1]]
[1] "Fig"

[[5]]$data[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1

[[5]]$data[[1]][[3]]
[1] 37


[[5]]$data[[2]]
[[5]]$data[[2]][[1]]
[1] "Tony"

[[5]]$data[[2]][[2]]
[1] 1

[[5]]$data[[2]][[3]]
[1] 37
```

You can see that `name`, `y` and `PerTotal` are not defined.

Any ideas on why they are not being shown?

Below is the full code:

```
library (tidyr)
library (data.table)
library (highcharter)

x <- c("Farm","Farm","Farm","City","City","City","Ocean","Ocean")
y <- c("Sheep","Sheep","Cow","Car","Bus","Bus","Boat","Boat")
z <- c("Bill","Tracy","Sandy","Bob","Carl","Newt","Fig","Tony")
a <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
b <- c(3,5,1,3,8,5,3,9)

dat <- data.frame(x,y,z,a)


#First Tier #Copied
datSum <- dat %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarize(Quantity = sum(a)
  )
datSum <- arrange(datSum,desc(Quantity))
Lvl1dfStatus <- tibble(name = datSum$x, y = datSum$Quantity, drilldown = tolower(name))


Level_2_Drilldowns <- lapply(unique(dat$x), function(x_level) {
  # x_level is what you called 'input' earlier.
  datSum2 <- dat[dat$x == x_level,]

  datSum2 <- datSum2 %>%
    group_by(y) %>%
    summarize(Quantity = sum(a),
              PerTotal = sum(b)
    )
  datSum2 <- arrange(datSum2,desc(Quantity))

  Lvl2dfStatus <- tibble(name = datSum2$y,y = datSum2$Quantity, PerTotal = datSum2$PerTotal, drilldown = tolower(paste(x_level, name, sep = "_")))

  list(id = tolower(x_level), type = "column", data = list_parse(Lvl2dfStatus))
})

Level_3_Drilldowns <- lapply(unique(dat$x), function(x_level) {

  datSum2 <- dat[dat$x == x_level,]

  lapply(unique(datSum2$y), function(y_level) {

    datSum3 <- datSum2[datSum2$y == y_level,]

    datSum3 <- datSum3 %>%
      group_by(z) %>%
      summarize(Quantity = sum(a),
                PerTotal = sum(b)
      )
    datSum3 <- arrange(datSum3,desc(Quantity))

    Lvl3dfStatus <- tibble(name = datSum3$z,y = datSum3$Quantity, PerTotal = datSum3$PerTotal)

    list(id = tolower(paste(x_level, y_level, sep = "_")), type = "column", data = list_parse2(Lvl3dfStatus))
  })
}) %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)
```

Comment: what's `list_parse2()`?

Comment: same as `list_parse()`, it creates a list out of the data.table but it removes the `name` associated with it. I use it in the drilldown feature to let the users know they can't drilldown anymore (in Shiny it will show a blue underline for drilldown ability)

Comment: I was trying to reproduce your problem and got an error on that function... you might want to include the code for it, or remove it from your example code to simplify it.

Comment: When I remove the last `list` call, the Level_3_Drilldowns list I get identifies name, y and perTotal in all the elements. I guess that means the problem is in that last call, but I can't run it without the code for `list_parse2()`.

Comment: `list_parse2()` is from a package I did not include, I've updated the code to represent it. (`highcharter`)

Comment: But you are right, changing `list_parse2()` to `list_parse()` works